# TYPO3 powermail Datepicker - TYPO3

Tags: typo3, extbase, powermail

TYPO3 Powermail date picker is showing as regular input field in mozilla firefox. The field is showing as date field in chrome. How can it fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution.I installed the older version.The latest version provides the jquery datepicker in mozilla.We should set the locallang for the date format.

```
plugin.tx_powermail {
    _LOCAL_LANG {
        default {
            datepicker_format_date = d.m.Y
            datepicker_format_time = d.m.Y H:i:s
            datepicker_format_datetime = H:i:s
        }
        fr {
            datepicker_format_date = d.m.Y
            datepicker_format_time = d.m.Y H:i:s
            datepicker_format_datetime = H:i:s
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Firefox don't support native date fields. That's why a JavaScript datepicker should be rendered automatically (difference to Chrome) in powermail.

Of course the JavaScript datepicker can only be rendered, if jQuery was included and if the ordering of the JavaScript is correct. Please check your browser console on JavaScript errors.

Example for a working form can be seen in powermail testparcours: http://powermail.in2code.ws/index.php?id=28

Some information: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/ForEditors/AddANewForm/FieldDate/Index.html#date-formats

Answer (score 1):

Firefox does not support date fields. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: Then how can I overcome the limitation?

Comment: Provide a patch to firefox, or add a javascript datepicker to your site.